# Visual studio code

Tags: vsto, visual-studio-code

I am working on visual studio and all of a sudden I can't use the backspace anymore, whenever I try using it, it gives me this warning. " no handler found for the command: 'extension.vim_backspace'. an extension might be missing an activation event"

Comment: do you use latest version of vscode?

Comment: Yes I am useing the latest

Comment: I've replicated this. Maybe file an issue?

Comment: I have uninstalled it and reinstalled it, it seems different but didn't give me that error